# Docker WordPress image does not persist wp-content when creating new docker images

Tags: wordpress, docker

let me clarify the situation:

---

1. Run wordpress docker container with:

   **docker run --name wp -d -p 80:80 wordpress**

---

2. Login to a running container using bash:

   **docker exec -it wp /bin/bash**

---

3. Create 2 dummy files:

   *One in root:*

   **touch /xxx**

   *One in wp-content/themes*

   **touch /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/xxx**

---

4. Create a new wordpress image:

   **docker commit wp new_wp**

---

5. Kill the original container:

   **docker kill wp**

---

6. Run new docker image:

   **docker run --name new_wp -d -p 80:80 new_wp**

---

7. Inspect dummy files created in step 3:

   *Dummy file in root exists*

   *Dummy file in wp-content/themes **no longer exists**!!!*

---

**Questions:**

1. Can anyone explain such a bizare behaviour in step 7?
2. What am I supposed to do to persist wp-content data?

P.S. I am deploying to AWS ECS Fargate instances therefore using volumes is not very practical for me. Ideally - I would love to have everything under one image without files disappearing from *wp-content* directory.

Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docker image for wordpress [includes a VOLUME statement](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/41af7e24571774b8016b930bfb767c39552d0a02/php7.3/apache/Dockerfile#L99):

```
VOLUME /var/www/html
```

This forces a volume to be created on any resulting containers even if you do not specify one in your `docker run` command. Without a specification, you will get an anonymous volume with a long unique id that can be seen in `docker volume ls`.

The `docker commit` command (which I strongly recommend against using in any workflow that you want repeatability) only captures changes to the container filesystem (you can see these with `docker container diff`). The changes to the volume are not part of the container filesystem, and therefore will not be included in this commit.

To persist data, you should be defining and using a volume, e.g.:

```
docker run --name wp -v wpdata:/var/www/html -d -p 80:80 wordpress
```

Comment: Thank you. But i have clearly staded that using volumes is not an option for me.

Comment: @LaimonasSutkus whether or not they are an option for you use case, you are using them because of the image you have selected.

Comment: Unless you know how to deploy AWS Fargate instances that use volumes in which we have all wp-content and other data defined.

Comment: Understood. So maybe copying a wordpress Dockerfile and modifying it (deleting that VOLUME statement) would do the trick :)

Comment: @LaimonasSutkus you would both remove the `VOLUME` and add any other changes you want to the image, eliminating the need to perform a `docker commit`.

Comment: Well, the idea is that I push new versions of images (with new plugins/themes) to a private AWS ECR repository which automatically triggers a deployment. So if i want to release a change I do the `docker commit` and push it to ECR repository.

Comment: @LaimonasSutkus My advice is to use a Dockerfile that installs plugins/themes as part of `docker build`. A `docker commit` tends to indicate manual and non reproduceable steps that are not automated.

Comment: Specific to wordpress are the following details on how to pre-install themes: https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/246#issuecomment-340557707 and https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/341

Comment: Thank you for the references. Well, i have all of my scripts in place to automate `docker commit` flows therefore there is 0 manual work. Also, just wanted to say, that copying `Dockerfile` from oficial github repo and removing `VOLUME` line solved all the issues! :)

Comment: P.S. This is the library that i use to push/commit docker images. 
https://pypi.org/project/aws-ecr-migration/
P.P.S. I wrote this some time ago to automate wordpress images pushing to ECR.

Answer (score 2):

Docket is inherently non-persistent.

If you want to leverage docker for WP I highly recommend offloading image asset management to S3 and Cloudfront.